# Auto-linebreak in table - tabular/longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I have the following longtable where i want the third column to do an auto-linebreak, instead of me having to do it forced. Is there any way to do this?

This is a image of how the long table looks, where i did forced linebreaks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFeY.jpg "how the long table looks"

This is how the table in the code below looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nklKY.jpg "from code example"

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{\textbf{Veterinarian and pet shop interview analysis}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Theme} & \textbf{Sub theme} & \textbf{Raw data} & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Findings} & \textbf{+/-} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Theme} & \textbf{Sub theme} & \textbf{Raw data} & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Findings} & \textbf{+/-} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Increase\\ of overwe-\\ ight dogs \\ in Denmark\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Measurement\\ method\end{tabular} & \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Vet: Many sources tell that it is increasing and this is somewhat based on the veterinarian's experiences and impressions.\\ PS: We often see in the shop that many of the dogs who enter are overweight. Actually it is so big a problem that the shop i am in have chosen to put up a dog weight in the shop, so that the customers can weight their dog when they come in here.\end{tabular}} & VP1.1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Increase \\ of overweight \\ dogs in \\ Denmark is \\ based on \\ estimates\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}+\\ +\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `p{<width>}` as you have at the top will enable automatic line-breaking. It isn't clear which bit you are referring to by the 'third column' given that you seem to have multiple tables there.  What is the point of the nested `tabular`s with only one column?

Comment: If you post a complete example people can copy-paste-compile you are more likely to get effective help. What do the `+`s do? Using `H` for `longtable` is pointless. It won't float anyway, so you don't need to stop it.

Comment: What is you paper size? Your column widths don't seem to fit usual sizes.

Comment: Sorry, the width of the column was just something i tried to force the line breaks, but the text just went out of the cell then. Edited the code now. The column im talking about is the third one after the line that says "\endlastfoot". Everything before that is just to give the long table af "headline" row on all pages.

Comment: @cfr If you copy the code you are able to compile, if you have the pacages. I can compile it no problem in my editor.
Paper size is A4.

Comment: Kenneth, the example cannot compile. The documentclass, the packages, the `document` environment are missing.

Comment: Looking closely at the example, @cfr already mentioned all important things. Use a `p` column. And better not nest tables, it just creates confusion and makes the table much harder to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already hinted in the very first comment, using `p` columns with an appropriate width is the solution to prevent manual line breaking.

I don't know why you are nesting tabulars. You might be looking for `m` columns. I changed the table in its implementation quite a bit and adjusted the width by trial and error.

[image: kennethLongtable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,showframe,textheight=10cm}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m}
\newcommand{\tabhead}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\bfseries#2}}
\newcommand{\positive}{$+$ }
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\renewcommand{\positive}{\checkmark\space}
\newcommand{\negative}{$-$ }
%\renewcommand{\negative}{$\times$ }
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|K{.12\linewidth}|K{.13\linewidth}|>{\itshape}K{.34\linewidth}|K{.07\linewidth}|K{.11\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.03\linewidth}|}
        \caption{\textbf{Veterinarian and pet shop interview analysis}}\\
        \hline
        \tabhead{|c|}{Theme} & \tabhead{c|}{Sub theme} & \tabhead{c|}{Raw data} &
        \tabhead{c|}{Code} & \tabhead{c|}{Findings} & \tabhead{c|}{+/-} \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
        {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline
        \tabhead{|c|}{Theme} & \tabhead{c|}{Sub theme} & \tabhead{c|}{Raw data} &
        \tabhead{c|}{Code} & \tabhead{c|}{Findings} & \tabhead{c|}{+/-} \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        1. Increase of overweight dogs  in Denmark & Measurement method &
        Vet: Many sources tell that it is increasing and this is somewhat
        based on the veterinarian's experiences and impressions. \par PS: We
        often see in the shop that many of the dogs who enter are
        overweight. Actually it is so big a problem that the shop i am in
        have chosen to put up a dog weight in the shop, so that the
        customers can weight their dog when they come in here. &
        VP1.1 & 1.~Increase  of overweight  dogs in  Denmark is  based on
        estimates & \positive \positive \\ \hline
        1. Increase of overweight dogs  in Denmark & Measurement method &
        Vet: Many sources tell that it is increasing and this is somewhat
        based on the veterinarian's experiences and impressions. \par PS: We
        often see in the shop that many of the dogs who enter are
        overweight. Actually it is so big a problem that the shop i am in
        have chosen to put up a dog weight in the shop, so that the
        customers can weight their dog when they come in here. &
        VP1.1 & 1.~Increase  of overweight  dogs in  Denmark is  based on
        estimates & \positive \negative  \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Am i doing something wrong or is there something wrong with your code? This puts my entire document in cells. Sorry, i am rather new to latex.

Comment: Play around to find out what causes the behaviour. I can only assume, that you don't know what option `showframe` is doing.